# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_jobs'

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pip

This error is cause due to following line
`model = DBSCAN(eps=2.5, min_samples=3, n_jobs=1)`

As I seen other answers and previous issues on GitHub, I came to know that problem occurs due to old version of `scikit-learn`

I've updated my `scikit-learn`

```
➜  Code sudo -H  pip install -U scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
Downloading scikit_learn-0.19.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl 
(12.2MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 12.2MB 68kB/s 
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.18
 Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.18:
   Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.18
Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.19.0
```

But when I checked version again it shows 0.16.1

```
>>> import sklearn

>>> print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))

    The scikit-learn version is 0.16.1.
```

I'm not sure but does this problem exists because `scikit-learn` is installed on multiple paths ? 
How to fix the version of `scikit-learn` ?

Or there is any other reason for the `TypeError` ?

In any of above case, please suggest a solution

Comment: Yes, this error is because of the issue you pointed. See the [documentation of DBSCAN in ver 0.16](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN). It has no `n_jobs` parameter.

Comment: But after updating sklearn, why the version is still 0.16

Comment: That's depending on the command. Why are you using sudo -H and not simply sudo?

Comment: I don't think that's issue, I'm using this flag due to multiple users

Comment: Then you should check the paths of where you are installing the newer version and where the old version is installed